# Why can't service account such as Local Service, Network Service, or Local System be managed on a domain level?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis

I read from [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548356.aspx) that:

> On a local computer, an administrator
>   can configure the application to run
>   as Local Service, Network Service, or
>   Local System. These service accounts
>   are simple to configure and use but
>   are typically shared among multiple
>   applications and services and cannot
>   be managed on a domain level.

I just don't understand why these accounts cannot be managed on a domain level, since they all have well-known SIDs?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 8):

These are "universal well-known SIDs"; they are the same for every machine and do not have the "domain identifier" component, therefore they cannot be associated with any particular domain. (If they did, joining a machine to a domain would break *a lot* of stuff, particularly ACLs.)

For example, a normal user SID looks like `S-1-5-21-2814603912-1974576649-1524133500-1001`.

Here, *`21`* is SECURITY_NT_NON_UNIQUE, *`2814603912-1974576649-1524133500`* is the domain identifier and *`1013`* is the relative ID.

In comparison, `LOCAL SYSTEM` has the SID `S-1-5-18`.

---

FWIW, these three accounts [are not even real accounts in the SAM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684190%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). They are predefined in Windows itself.